# Border-radius on some childs pixeled and less than parent's radius

Tags: css

When I putted child input into a div and setting them the same border-radius, I got this.

[image]

Comment: Could you please help us recreate the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Reduce the radius of the inner by whatever the border width is of the outer.

Comment: It didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the element with the class of `itemName`, inside of the element with the class of `item`.

If so, you shouldn't need to put any border-radius on the `itemName` styling at all, it will automatically curve the bottom corners with the parent element.

https://codepen.io/TBackens/pen/LYbqQpv

Comment: No, I meant that when increasing the border radius, I get the effect when the child seems to have a border radius smaller than that of the parent and the background begins to shine through.

Comment: Then don't set the border-radius of the child, just leave it blank.

Comment: I might not be understanding your question, maybe give me a full codepen, with everything?